# How to handle pre-registered users and avoid duplication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, authentication, registration

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle this situation:

User signs up -> creates a group -> adds users to the group

Added user comes to the site -> signs up -> sets up a different group

There are two classes of "user" here: registered(who log into the web-app) and non-registered(who can interact with the app purely via email due to them being added to a group). I have a boolean field for "registered".

A user that comes to the site and creates a group is "registered". A user that is just added to a group is not.

What I want to do is run a check when a new user is created to see if they are already in our database and in a non-registered state. Their email must be unique so essentially new users that are already a member of another group need their data updating rather than a creation of new users.

I also thought about separating my db schema into Users and Members then upgrading Members to Users if they come to the site and sign up, instead of just integrating with the app over email.

What do you guys think?

(Thanks in advance.)

Comment: You should start by looking at [ActiveRecord Validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have separate tables if the only difference is a state/role; just see if they're already in the system, and if they are, flip their state.

Comment: Thanks. I have a "registered" attribute for each User. To flip it would I add something like `User.registered = true` to my UsersController?